# No space left on device, when my device is 30% full! Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, windows, dual-boot, disk-usage, disk

I have a device (2 TB SSD NTFS formatted) which isn't full. Is working fine on windows (dual boot), but causes this issue on ubuntu.
The device is `/media/yoni/4692E49292E4882F`

`df -Thi` output:

```
(yonienv1) yoni@Garfield:~$ df -iTh
Filesystem     Type     Inodes IUsed IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev           devtmpfs    16M   670   16M    1% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs       16M  1.3K   16M    1% /run
/dev/sdb4      ext4        61M  841K   60M    2% /
tmpfs          tmpfs       16M   278   16M    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs          tmpfs       16M     5   16M    1% /run/lock
tmpfs          tmpfs       16M    18   16M    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop1     squashfs    733   733     0  100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/123
/dev/loop2     squashfs    15K   15K     0  100% /snap/sublime-text/85
/dev/loop4     squashfs    44K   44K     0  100% /snap/vlc/1397
/dev/loop3     squashfs    13K   13K     0  100% /snap/core/8268
/dev/loop5     squashfs    28K   28K     0  100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/91
/dev/loop6     squashfs   1.6K  1.6K     0  100% /snap/gnome-calculator/406
/dev/loop10    squashfs    354   354     0  100% /snap/gnome-logs/81
/dev/loop14    squashfs    354   354     0  100% /snap/gnome-logs/61
/dev/loop9     squashfs   1.6K  1.6K     0  100% /snap/gnome-calculator/544
/dev/loop0     squashfs    13K   13K     0  100% /snap/core/8039
/dev/loop11    squashfs    29K   29K     0  100% /snap/cmake/203
/dev/loop15    squashfs    733   733     0  100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/111
/dev/loop13    squashfs    274   274     0  100% /snap/gnome-characters/375
/dev/loop8     squashfs   9.9K  9.9K     0  100% /snap/core18/1279
/dev/loop18    squashfs    271   271     0  100% /snap/gnome-characters/367
/dev/loop7     squashfs    28K   28K     0  100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/110
/dev/loop12    squashfs    41K   41K     0  100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1353
/dev/loop17    squashfs   9.9K  9.9K     0  100% /snap/core18/1288
/dev/loop16    squashfs    39K   39K     0  100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1313
/dev/nvme0n1p2 vfat          0     0     0     - /boot/efi
tmpfs          tmpfs       16M    39   16M    1% /run/user/1000
/dev/nvme0n1p4 fuseblk    1.3G  3.0M  1.3G    1% /media/yoni/4692E49292E4882F
/dev/sdb2      fuseblk    4.5G  589K  4.5G    1% /media/yoni/Yoni6TB1
/dev/sda2      fuseblk    5.3G  2.6M  5.3G    1% /media/yoni/Yoni6TB0
```

`df` output:

```
(yonienv1) yoni@Garfield:~$ df
Filesystem      1K-blocks      Used  Available Use% Mounted on
udev             65821536         0   65821536   0% /dev
tmpfs            13169132      2320   13166812   1% /run
/dev/sdb4       992570136  79935996  862144592   9% /
tmpfs            65845652    584120   65261532   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                5120         4       5116   1% /run/lock
tmpfs            65845652         0   65845652   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop1           3840      3840          0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/123
/dev/loop2          69248     69248          0 100% /snap/sublime-text/85
/dev/loop4         207872    207872          0 100% /snap/vlc/1397
/dev/loop3          91264     91264          0 100% /snap/core/8268
/dev/loop5         159872    159872          0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/91
/dev/loop6           4224      4224          0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/406
/dev/loop10          1024      1024          0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/81
/dev/loop14          1024      1024          0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/61
/dev/loop9           4352      4352          0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/544
/dev/loop0          91264     91264          0 100% /snap/core/8039
/dev/loop11        103808    103808          0 100% /snap/cmake/203
/dev/loop15          3840      3840          0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/111
/dev/loop13         15104     15104          0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/375
/dev/loop8          55936     55936          0 100% /snap/core18/1279
/dev/loop18         15104     15104          0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/367
/dev/loop7         160512    160512          0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/110
/dev/loop12         45312     45312          0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1353
/dev/loop17         55936     55936          0 100% /snap/core18/1288
/dev/loop16         43904     43904          0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1313
/dev/nvme0n1p2      97280     31605      65675  33% /boot/efi
tmpfs            13169128        52   13169076   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/nvme0n1p4 1999818748 627767368 1372051380  32% /media/yoni/4692E49292E4882F
/dev/sdb2      4850516408  50451580 4800064828   2% /media/yoni/Yoni6TB1
/dev/sda2      5860504572 219583484 5640921088   4% /media/yoni/Yoni6TB0
```

`du -sh .` output (it takes about 5 mins as I'm storing about 3M small files there):

```
(yonienv1) yoni@Garfield:/media/yoni/4692E49292E4882F$ du -sh .
596G    .
```

sudo sfdisk -l /dev/nvme0n1p4 output:

```
(yonienv1) yoni@Garfield:/media/yoni/4692E49292E4882F$ sudo sfdisk -l /dev/nvme0n1p4
Disk /dev/nvme0n1p4: 1.9 TiB, 2047814402048 bytes, 3999637504 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x73736572

Device           Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/nvme0n1p4p1      1920221984 3736432267 1816210284   866G 72 unknown
/dev/nvme0n1p4p2      1936028192 3889681299 1953653108 931.6G 6c unknown
/dev/nvme0n1p4p3               0          0          0     0B  0 Empty
/dev/nvme0n1p4p4        27722122   27722568        447 223.5K  0 Empty

Partition table entries are not in disk order.
```

The windows OS is stored on this device and this is the output for
sudo fdisk -l /dev/nvme0n1:

```
(yonienv1) yoni@Garfield:/media/yoni/4692E49292E4882F$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/nvme0n1
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 1.9 TiB, 2048408248320 bytes, 4000797360 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: B7D6369D-AE47-4E8F-8436-021FD73817B7

Device           Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1    2048     923647     921600  450M Windows recovery environment
/dev/nvme0n1p2  923648    1126399     202752   99M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p3 1126400    1159167      32768   16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/nvme0n1p4 1159168 4000796671 3999637504  1.9T Microsoft basic data
```

The exact model is: ADATA XPG SX8200 Pro PCIe NVMe M.2 2280 2TB SSD ASX8200PNP-2TT-C.
nvme list output:

```
(yonienv1) yoni@Garfield:/media/yoni/4692E49292E4882F/dbs$ sudo nvme list
Node             SN                   Model                                    Namespace Usage                      Format           FW Rev  
---------------- -------------------- ---------------------------------------- --------- -------------------------- ---------------- --------
/dev/nvme0n1     2J3420178126         ADATA SX8200PNP                          1         622.52  GB /   2.05  TB    512   B +  0 B   SS0411BB
```

Comment: What did you do to get the "no space" message?

Comment: could you please append `sudo sfdisk -l /dev/<your-device>`

Comment: @ChristopherDíazRiveros Done

Comment: @ajgringo619 Downloaded some files from the internet. THis disk has millions of files, and some AI is moving the files from one folder to another (most are being deleted) with a AI-based python script.

Comment: problem seems to be your Ubuntu does not recognize the type of device, most likely due to lack of drivers, you can see that two main blocks from sfdisk show an `unknown` type and both are over 900Gb big, can you give me the device manufacturer?

Comment: @ChristopherDíazRiveros The exact model is: ADATA XPG SX8200 Pro PCIe NVMe M.2 2280 2TB SSD ASX8200PNP-2TT-C. Wait,what is the partition /dev/nvme0n1p4p4 and why is it so small? I was able to save about 3 million files on it. I'm so confused :(

Comment: @yonikeren, not a ubuntu user, but try `sudo apt install ntfs-3g`, you should install a package, if not, it should yield for the proper package name, once installed, reboot, and it should load everything correctly, you can know by using the same `sfdisk` command

Comment: @ChristopherDíazRiveros it outputs  ntfs-3g is already the newest version (1:2017.3.23-2ubuntu0.18.04.2)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103235/discussion-between-christopher-diaz-riveros-and-yoni-keren).

Comment: Could you show us something that indicates there is a problem? All of your output here looks fine. Can you `touch` new files? How about `head -c 100 /dev/urandom > file` does that work?

Comment: @terdon This error happens now only when I try to copy a few bigger files(a few jpg files) to it eg it's not 100% full. Will it help you if I'll make whatever it is 100% full? Looking at the output again, maybe it has something to do with the partition /dev/nvme0n1p4p4? It seems almost full...Or maybe not since its size is about 200KB and I moved a few GBs using linux onto this disk. Christopher suggests that it has something to do with the "unknown" labels (see above).

Comment: Can you run `fdisk -l /dev/nvme0n1` ? `fdisk -l /dev/nvme0n1p4` is showing garbage values because fdisk expects its argument to be a drive, not a single partition

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Done! Oh wow,1.9T of "Microsoft basic data"...but it did let me write a few GBs hmmm I installed windows first,and then ubuntu I guess this is the cause....ok what do i do now? :P

Comment: @yonikeren Please give us some outputs as terdon said, we can't evaluate your words like "millions of files" -- we need to see outputs and commands you have used to generate them. (Until then, I see nothing wrong with for example running `sudo nvme list` to get the version of your firmware and if older than currently available, then update it. I myself update my NVMe firmware asap as it can come with some problems resolutions.)

Comment: @LinuxSecurityFreak I can't share the script files that get (and analyze...) those files... sudo nvme list output sudo: nvme: command not found

Comment: @LinuxSecurityFreak installed nvme and added the output to the question

Answer (score 1):

Normally, when you see a *no space left* error in Linux, it could be because the system either runs out of block storage or it runs out of [inodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode).

Since you mentioned you still have free space (block) in your system, you can check whether you still have any [inodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode) left, by running:

```
df -i
```

Running out of [inodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode) is commonly found in a system where there are many small files.

Comment: The output of `df -i` is the first thing in the question, so we know it can't be that.

Comment: This answer was written a long time after I've showed the free inodes output in the question...

Comment: I think thus far a good answer for future readers. +1